# Checking the elements in an array using a for loop to ensure they are the right datatype, but answer is printing too many times

Tags: c

I'm currently trying to iterate over an argv array in order to check the individual elements. The loop is working correctly however the `printf` function is printing too many times(proportional to the number of elements the user provides at the command line). I was wondering if anyone could help me to iterate over the individual array elements whilst only printing the answer once.

```
if(argc == 2)
{
    //when the ith position of the first index of argv does not equal null move across to the next ith value 

    int key = atoi(argv[1]);       
    for(int i = 0; argv[1][i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        //check each character at the command line is a decimal digit

       int currentchar = argv[1][i];
       if (isdigit(currentchar))
       {
           printf("success\n");
           printf("%i\n", key);
       }
       else
       {
           printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
           return 1;    
       }
```

Comment: declare success out of the for loop.

Comment: s/declare/define/.

Comment: in general, do not post code snippets,  rather post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. contains a good method to show a 'USAGE' error message

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>  // fprintf(), printf()
#include <stdlib.h> // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <ctype.h>  // isdigit()

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <saesar key>\n", argv[0] );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    int validKey = 1;  // indicate valid key

    for(int i = 0; argv[1][i]; i++)
    {
        //check each character at the command line is a decimal digit
        if ( !isdigit( argv[1][i] ) )
        {
            validKey = 0;   // indicate invalid key
        }
    }

    if( validKey )
    {
        printf("success\n");
        printf("%i\n", atoi(argv[1]) );
    }

    else
    { // invalid key
        printf( "key: %s is invalid\n", argv[1] );
    } 
}
```

Comment: you could `break;` after `validKey = 0`. No need to go through the rest of argv[1] characters.

Comment: The code 'could' have that break, especially if execution time were a key factor